# How to hide ionic keyboard in Auto focus

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, autofocus, ionic-keyboard

I am using Ionic 3 and Angular 5. I have a text-area with Auto focus.
problem is, I do not want to show keyboard in auto focus. How can I hide keyboard in Auto focus.
Here is my code.

```
 setTimeout(() => {
  this.myInput.setFocus();
},1000);
```

This code is for Auto focus.

```
<ion-textarea style="color:red; opacity: 0;" #input id="myInput" rows="1" maxLength="500"  [(ngModel)]="details" (ionChange)="Scan($event)" ></ion-textarea>
```

This is HTML code
please help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for hiding keyboard

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

constructor(private keyboard: Keyboard) { }

...

this.keyboard.show();

this.keyboard.close();
```

Comment: Unfortunately when running `this.keyboard.close()` it loses focus of the input field

Comment: Right.. But then the keyboard pops up. There is no way to focus an input while keeping the keyboard closed? This is what the OP describes and it's also the issue I'm trying to solve as well.
>I do not want to show keyboard in auto focus

Comment: @thefoyer Did you find any solution to hide the keyword while focusing the input field?